# Storm - Supervisors launched but not connecting to Nimbus

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have a Storm cluster with 1 Nimbus, 4 Supervisors and 2 Zookeeper nodes. My `Storm.yaml` is as following:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "storage14"
    - "storage15"

nimbus.seeds: ["storage01"]

#storm.local.hostname: "storage05"
supervisor.supervisors:
    - "storage02"
    - "storage03"
    - "storage04"
    - "storage05"

storm.local.dir: "/tmp/storm"

worker.childopts: "-Xmx%HEAP-MEM%m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:artifacts/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump"
```

This storm.yaml file is used by both Nimbus and Supervisors. When Nimbus is started I have the `storm.local.hostname` commented out as is shown above.

However, when starting Supervisors on respective nodes, I uncomment the `storm.local.hostname` and set it to the hostname of the node on which the supervisor is being launched. For instance if I was launching the supervisor on storage05, the storm.yaml file would have the following additional config param:

```
storm.local.hostname: "storage05"
```

The problem is even though **Nimubs** is launched successfully and I can see it on the Storm UI, some **supervisors** do not seem to be able to connect to **Nimbus**. For instance of the 4 nodes I start **supervisors** on, Storm UI often shows only 2 of them connected. However, if I `ssh` in to these nodes and run `jps`, I can see that the **supervisor** process is running on ALL of these nodes.

The Supervisors at the nodes which do end up connecting are not the same always, so it is definitely not a problem with those specific nodes.

Another thing to notice is if I try to execute a topology on whatever nodes that got connected, it does not get registered by the cluster and I can not see that topology on the UI either.

What do you think might be causing this erratic behavior?

**UPDATE:**
Tail end of nimbus.log has the following lines

```
2017-01-25 00:04:25.216 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [WARN] Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2017-01-25 00:04:25.317 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server storage15/192.168.140.195:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-01-25 00:04:25.317 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [WARN] Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2017-01-25 00:04:25.686 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server storage15/192.168.140.195:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-01-25 00:04:25.686 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [WARN] Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2017-01-25 00:04:25.787 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server storage14/192.168.140.194:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-01-25 00:04:25.787 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [WARN] Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Comment: 1. Which version do you use?
2. Is "storage05" accessible for all of nodes?
3. Is "storage05" recognized as 'Leader' from the UI?
4. Is there any error message on Nimbus log?

Comment: 1. I am at Storm 1.0.1 2. Yes, I can do a password less ssh from all nodes to each other, include storage05. 3. No, but I dont think that should be the case, as I am not launching the Nimbus from Storage05. Storage01 is the Nimbus and storage02-05 are supervisors. But yeah, storage01 is indeed recognized as leader by the UI.

Comment: Sorry I missed. If "storage01" is recognized as Leader it would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE (nimbus log) indicates that your Nimbus cannot connect Zookeeper cluster. Please check that Zookeeper cluster (storage14/storage15) is accessible from storage01 (not only node is accessible, but also do telnet to Zookeeper server via "telnet storage14 (and/or storage15) 2181").

When ZK connectivity issue is gone please try starting supervisor again.

Comment: I do not have telnet available on the cluster. But I went over this [thread](http://superuser.com/questions/621870/test-if-a-port-on-a-remote-system-is-reachable-without-telnet) and found that `nc` can be used as an alternative for `telnet`.
`nc -zv storage14 2181` and `nc -zv storage15 2181` both produce `Connection to storage14/15 2181 port [tcp/eforward] succeeded!` so it seems ZK is accessible from the Nimbus

Comment: Could you run `echo "ruok" | nc storage14 2181` or `echo "ruok" | nc storage15 2181` to see it returns `imok`? You can replace `ruok` to `stat` to see status of zookeeper cluster.

Comment: Both the commands return imok so the Zookeeper nodes seem to be working fine.